# How to use paper other than Letter, A4/5, B5, Legal, and Executive

Tags: paper-size

I had a document printed on A5 paper, using the option `\documentclass[a5paper]{article}`.  Now I need to print it in US, so it needs to be 5.5" x 8.5".  I could not find an option to do this.  Is this possible without including an extra package?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it is also unnecessarily more complicated. My advice is to use `\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in}`

Comment: Adding the geometry package increases PDF file size, which is a problem in my case.  Knowing how to do it without it is preferable, even if it's more complicated.

Comment: I compiled two documents that contain only a blank page, one with `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` and one with additionally loading the `geometry` package and setting the new page format. Both PDF files are virtually equal in size (the latter even smaller by 6 bytes).

Comment: @JasperHabicht I confirmed this also; so I guess now my problem has been reduced to one I can hopefully solve by myself: figuring out where the difference in the file size comes in in my document.

Comment: The `memoir` class, which I realise you are not using, has a `statementpaper` option. Statement paper is the word for the US paper size you are after. The class has some 33 paper size options.